# AES encryption option for offline usage

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

My objective is to perform data encryption/decryption locally for some data such as personal information and so on, instead of password, within a mobile app. Stumbled upon this [library](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#documentation), and now considering two options which I can have

**Option 1**
Using user's password as `secret passphrase`, instead of hardcoding a `passphrase`, encryption and decryption key are "customized"

```js
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
​
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
```

**Option 2** Generating a key based on user's password such as below

```js
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("password", salt, {
  keySize: 512 / 32,
  iterations: 10000,
});

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key.toString());
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key.toString());
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Given my use case, I'm wondering if there is any advantages of one option over another?

Comment: If would prefer option 2 because the key derivation is more standardized that the one in option 1 (and more flexible regarding the parameters). Just a note: the keySize (512 / 32) gives an 16 byte long key for AES 128, I would set this to (1024/32) for an AES-256 key. Second: why do you use key.toString() and not directly the generated key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Neither* of these two options can be recommended:

- The first option should definitely not be used unless compatibility reasons enforce this.

  The main reason for this is that the built-in key derivation applies the deprecated key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()`, which derives a 32 bytes key (AES-256) and a 16 bytes IV.
  `EVP_BytesToKey()` and the pararmeters used for key derivation (MD5, iteration count of 1) are considered insecure today, s. e.g. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139).
  In addition, as already mentioned in the comment, `EVP_BytesToKey()` is a proprietary and non-standard implementation of OpenSSL, and is therefore not available on many platforms, which can be a problem in a cross-platform architecture.

  The clearly more secure alternative is to apply a standardized key derivation function such as PBKDF2 to derive a key that is then used for encryption/decryption.
- The second option uses PBKDF2 as key derivation function though, but performs a hexadecimal encoding of the key with `key.toString()`, i.e. converts the key to a string, with far-reaching consequences:

  CryptoJS just uses the data type to interpret the second parameter as password or key. In case of a string the data is interpreted as password and the key derivation with `EVP_BytesTokey()` is performed (as for the first option), in case of a `WordArray` the data is interpreted as key which is *directly* applied.

  The current implementation passes the key as string, i.e. the key derived with PBKDF2 is interpreted as password and the built-in key derivation with `EVP_BytesTokey()` is unnecessarily performed *in addition* to the key derivation with PBKDF2.

###### The correct approach:

Change the second option so that the key is passed as `WordArray`, i.e. `key` instead of `key.toString()`.
This change has the consequence that salt and IV must be handled *explicitly* (in contrast to the built-in key derivation with `EVP_BytesToKey()`, where this happens under the hood):

- The current code already generates a random salt, which is perfectly correct. Similarly, a random IV must be generated (CryptoJS uses CBC by default) and passed (s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv)).
  As an alternative to explicit generation with `random()`, the IV can be derived together with the key via PBKDF2.
- Since salt and IV are needed for decryption and are not secret, both are usually concatenated with the ciphertext: `salt|IV|ciphertext` (if the IV is derived together with the key, of course only the salt needs to be concatenated). On the decryption side, the portions can be separated based on the known lengths of salt and IV.

---

Regarding the key size mentioned in the comment: All AES variants are considered secure today, even the smallest key size AES-128.
Whether AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256 should be used depends on the respective requirements. If the highest possible security is needed e.g. with regard to future quantum computers, AES-256 is probably the better choice. However, this requirement may not always exist. See e.g. also the post [Why most people use 256 bit encryption instead of 128 bit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14068).

Answer (score 0):

You should never hard code a passphrase, it turns cryptography into encoding.

The use of hashing instead of standard human readable text stings is preferable, especially as it adds what i assume are iteration hashing which increase workload against brute force attacks. 1000 iterations adds quite some time, 10k even more, but everything that consume CPU cycles need to be balanced against performance.

Also make sure that any encoding you use (like Utf8) when reading/writing data is explicitly set so you don't mix and match types, that can cause some problems.